# Instantiate a PresenterWidget (GWTP) manually

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

i am new to GWT, GWTP.

I have a PresenterWidget which gets instantiated multiple times and gets added to a slot. I want to define the amount of instances programmatically. I only know that I make a new Instance of the Widget by Injecting it.

```java
@Inject MyWidgetPresenter first; 
@Inject MyWidgetPresenter second; 
// ...
```

Can I instantiate it with new? how do instantiate the view?

I tried to use a composite because it seemed to be the smartest solution, because it doesnt contain much logic anyway. But I cant add a composite to a slot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same problem atm and I just don't get what GWTP wants from me here ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `ClientGinjector` reference and call a getYourPresenter() method. If it's declared as `@Singleton` it will return the same instance, if is not will create a new instance, same as using new, but injecting all parameters to the constructor.
It will be the same as adding @Inject to a field.

Added:
If you don't have the required presenter there, at your `ClientGinjector`, you can simply write a getter method at that interface. Ex:

```java
public interface ClientGinjector extends Ginjector {
    ....
    SideMenuPresenter getSideMenuPresenter();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Excactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a nicer way of getting the reference than passing it to the constructor? public MainPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy, PlaceManager placeManager, ClientGinjector ginjector) { ... }

Comment: The ClientGinjector is instantiated at the EntryPoint. I keep it at an static reference. Then at any moment I can call Injector.get(). Injector is the class you can create that holds a reference to the ClientGinjector.

Answer (score 5):

In GWTP 1.0 the Ginjector is not needed anymore (auto-generated by gwtp).

In your case (and each time you need multiple instance of a class) the best is to inject a Provider of your WidgetPresenter:

```java
@Inject Provider<MyWidgetPresenter> myWidgetPresenterProvider;
```

Each time you need a new instance of MyWidegetPresenter, call the get() method on the provider :

```java
MyWidgetPresenter myWidgetPresenter = myWidgetPresenterProvider.get();
```

Comment: This answer should be idiomatic solution!