# Pass arguments to a number of PresenterWidget in GWTP

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have a GWTP `Presenter` in which I want to add an undetermined number of instances of GWTP `PresenterWidget`. To each of that instances I need to pass an argument (a different argument to each instance) that the parent `Presenter`owns.

There are two things that I need to accomplish here:

**1.** Instantiate an undetermined number of `PresenterWidget`

- Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966174/2819482), it looks like I just need a Provider.

**2.** Transfer to each of those `PresenterWidget` the argument I want.

- ProxyEvent does not seem an option since the PresenterWidget has no proxy
- I need to pass the argument before revealing the PresenterWidget
- Is it possible or is it a good practice to just declare a public method on the PresenterWidget and access it from the parent presenter?

For example:

```
public class MyWidgetPresenter extends PresenterWidget<MyWidgetPresenter.MyView>  {

...
    private MyArgument argument;
        public void setArgument(MyArgument argument){
        this.argument=argument;
    }
```

And then the Parent presenter could:

```
@Inject Provider<MyWidgetPresenter> myWidgetPresenterProvider;
...

[this could be part of a loop]
MyWidgetPresenter myWidgetPresenter = myWidgetPresenterProvider.get();
myWidgetPresenter.setArgument(argument);
getView().addToSlot(SLOT_MyWidgetPresenters, myWidgetPresenter);
[loop end]
```

Is this a valid solution at all? I have implemented it and everything works except that my PresenterWidget never calls onReveal or onReset which prevents to show the content. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this since I found where the problem is. Still I don't know if what I am doing is considered a good practice. [See Ümit's answer]

The reason why my WidgetPresenter was not calling onReveal() or onReset() was because I was calling the view's setInSlot, instead of the Presenter. This can be an easy mistake.

On your presenter never do this:

```
getView().setInSlot(whatever,whatever)
```

But rather

```
[this.] setInSlot(whatever,whatever)
```

Here is my code, for completeness sake:

The parent Presenter:

```
@Override
    public void onReset(){
        super.onReset();

        /* Request the Topic graph to show using RequestFactory*/
        TopicService service = requestFactory.topicService();
        service.getTopicGraph(movieId).with("entries").fire(new Receiver<TopicProxy>(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(TopicProxy response) {
                /* Clear whatever was in the slot before */
                getView().setInSlot(null, null);
                /* Get the Topic and set the title in this Presenter*/
                topic = response;
                getView().setMovieTitle(topic.getName());

                /* Then:
                 * - retrieve the Entries and add them to as many PresenterWidgets as needed
                 * - add those widgets to an slot on this Presenter
                 * - set on the PresenterWidget the Entry, that call also set's the child's view*/
                Iterator<EntryProxy> it = topic.getEntries().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    //TODO: pagination
                    ReviewPresenter myRP = myReviewPresenterProvider.get();
                    myRP.setEntry(it.next());
                    setInSlot(SLOT_movie, myRP);
                    reviewPresenterList.add(myRP);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error){
                getView().setMovieTitle(error.getMessage());
                //TODO use a label or go to error Place
            }

        });;
```

And the setEntry method on the PresenterWidget:

```
public void setEntry(EntryProxy entry){
    this.entry = entry;
    getView().setTextArea(entry.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to solve this problem, one of them is the way you showed in your own answer.

1. create a setter on your `PresenterWidget` and set it from your parent `Presenter` (how you have done it).
2. Fire an `Event` on the `EventBus` and handle it in your `PresenterWidgets` (The event contains the `EntryProxy` instance).
3. Let the `PresenterWidget` itself retrieve the data from the backend.

Solution 3 won't work in your case because you have not a single `PresenterWidget` but as many as you have data.

Solution 2 has the least coupling. However when you use `PresenterWidget`s you have anyways a coupling between your parent `Presenter` and your `PresenterWidget` so there is not much benefit.  I would only use this method if you want to use your retrieved `EntityProxy` elswhere (i.e. breadcrumb `PresenterWidget`).

Solution 1 (the one you suggested) is fine if you only deal with the `EntryProxy` in those `PresenterWidget`s.

Comment: Good point about solution 2. I don't think I need in this case but I will definitely need it for breadcrums. Thanks (I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet :S)